# What is the importance of taking bath in Kumbh waters?

Tags: puranas, rituals

What is the importance of taking bath in Prayagraj river (Confluence of Ganga, Yamuna and Saraswati) during Kumbh Mela (which happens every 12 years) ?

Comment: Similar Question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14365/does-taking-a-dip-in-the-ganges-river-actually-wash-away-your-sins